# Watson Voice Agent getting splited values in @sys-number

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson-dialog

first of all, I'm using Voice Agent with Watson Assistant, so everything here is in a phone call with Voice Agent.

I'm having trouble when prompting my users for their 'ticket' code for me to call my external API to get the status of the ticket. The problem is that the number is always a "big" integer, in this example: 123, so they don't speak it like: one hundred and twenty three, they say it like: one two three (and these values are sometimes more than a thousand). Then my @sys-number get this values:

```
@sys-number:1
@sys-number:2
@sys-number:3
```

This cause my sys-number to get only "1", because it was the first digit it recoginized. Is there a way to merge these values into one single variable?

Screenshot attached of the example dialog:
[image: Example dialog ss]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to convert the entity to a comma delimited array.

```
<? @sys-number.values.join(',') ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, in my case I had to use only "@sys-number.values", then I joined the array inside my IBM Cloud Function.