# How to get Watson Assistant to read numbers per digit instead of as a whole number

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

As the title suggests, I need Watson Assistant with phone integration to read back a number digit by digit instead of as a whole integer.

In this current setup, we are collecting an account ID and zip code from the user. We have a dialog node that confirms "is this the correct account id and zip?" But when reading back something like 12345 as the zip, instead of "your zip code is 1,2,3,4,5." It reads back "your zip code is twelve thousand three hundred and forty-five."

Is there a way to change how this number is read back to the user?

[image: The current slot setup]

Comment: Does the response read by the phone integration have the full integer (12345) or the digits (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)? Is your problem the reverse of this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52899411/watson-voice-agent-getting-splited-values-in-sys-number You can split or join strings.

Comment: Yes, it seems I'm having the opposite issue. My full 5-digit zip code is being stored into the local variable correctly (as the whole integer) even when someone reads off "my zip code is one, two, three, four, five". And when the voice agent is reading it back, it should be breaking up the integer and reading each digit individually, not as one large single integer.

Answer (score -1):

Not having implemented it, but you could

- turn the integer into a string,
- use [Array.split](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods#dialog-methods-arrays-split) to break up the string based on each digit,
- then [join it](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods#dialog-methods-arrays-join) back into a string using spaces to make it separate numbers to be read.